# Scrape 10 links in scrapy and then stop crawling the domain and start with another

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy. I have given a list of list of domains. What it actually does now is scrape the whole domain and search for pdf links and store it in a db. This process is asynchronous. 
I want to get 10 pdf links from each domain and stop the crawler.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

scrapy is all about parallelism, maybe do something like:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    allowed_domains = ['domain1.com', 'domain2.com', ... 'domain10.com']
    start_urls = ['http://domain1.com/index.html', 
                  'http://domain2.com/a.html', 
                  ...,
                  'http://domain10.com/b.html']
    ...

    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*a, **kw)
        self.domain_counters = collections.defaultdict(set)

    def parse(self, response):
        ....
        for link in sel.xpath("//a[contains(@href, '.pdf')"):
            # extract domain, 
            # note that url can be relative and take it from response
            domain = urlparse(...)
            # keep generating Requests as long as len(self.domain_counters[domain]) < 10
            self.domain_counters[domain].add(link)
            if len(self.domain_counters[domain]) < 10
                yield Request(url=link, callback=self.download_pdf)
```

note that crowling a few domains in parallel may slow the rhythm of hits on each one of them hence be more polite